# Git - Get back a single file from a previous commit

Tags: git

I cannot remember exactly what I did, but I think it was running `git rm -r --cached *`. I wanted to remove all files from staging.  To my surprise, the repo's `.gitignore` file was removed... although I am sure it will not surprise many of you.

How can I get that specific file back from a previous commit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use git checkout to get a specific file by providing a commit number and the file name.

`git checkout [commit-ref] -- [filename]`

[Git checkout](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout)

Comment: To make sure: this can  be regarded as the file getting practically "copied" back into the repo folder and then being ready to be committed again?

Comment: Yes you can think of it that way. It will checkout the file  and update the working directory  for the file to match the contents of the file at the time of the commit. You can then just stage and commit as usual.

Answer (score 1):

`git checkout HEAD -- .gitignore` will put it back on the working tree.